# way to stop code from crashing when file not found on the server?

Tags: python, file, loops, crash

So my problem is that my code would crash when one of it couldn't find the file in the server. Is there a way to skip that process of finding when there is no file found and continue through the loop.
Here is my code below:

`fname = '/Volumes/database/interpro/data/'+uniprotID+'.txt'`

```
for index, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):
        with open('output_'+uniprotID+'-%s.txt' % index,'w') as fileinput:
            print start, end
            for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
                item, start, end = map(int, (item, start, end)) #make sure that all value is int
                if start <= item <= end:
                    print item
                    result = str(item - start)
                    fileinput.write(">{0} | at position {1} \n".format(uniprotID, result))
                    fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                    break
            else:
                    fileinput.write(">{0} | N/A\n".format(uniprotID))
                    fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to handle the exception using a `try` / `except` block. See the Python docs for [handling exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

In this case, you'd have to wrap the `open()` call (and everything in that `with` block), with `try`, and catch the exception with `except IOError`:

```
for ...
    try:
        with open(...
           # do stuff
    except IOError:
        # what to do if file not found, or pass
```

---

*Additional info*

What you really should do, is pull the body of that outer `for` loop out into a function. Or maybe the body of the `with`, into a function that handles the opened file. Either way, cutting down on the nesting makes things much more readable, and easier to make changes like this, adding a `try`/`except`.

Actually, it appears that you are re-opening the file every iteration of the outer `for` loop, but the filename never changes - you are always re-opening the same file. Is that intentional? If not, you probably want to re-think your logic, and move that outside the loop.

On third thought, what is the exception you're getting? Is it a file not found IOError? Because you're opening the file for writing (`'w'`), so I'm not sure why you would get that exception anyway.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by wrap the open() call (and everything in that with block)??

Comment: that os what i got IOError: file not found

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):
    try:
        newname = 'output_'+uniprotID+'-%s.txt' % index
        with open(newname,'w') as fileinput:
            print start, end
            for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
                item, start, end = map(int, (item, start, end)) #make sure that all value is int
                if start <= item <= end:
                    print item
                    result = str(item - start)
                    fileinput.write(">{0} | at position {1} \n".format(uniprotID, result))
                    fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                    break
                else:
                    fileinput.write(">{0} | N/A\n".format(uniprotID))
                    fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
    except IOError:
        print 'Couldn't find file %s' % newname
```